# How to run from the command line in Ubuntu jupyter-notebook c python3

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I use pycharm to connect to a remote server via ssh from jupyter-notebook. I enter a token into pycharm, connect to check the version of python with the help of import sys print (sys.version) and it shows me that the second Python is being used. Please tell me what key is needed for the jupyter notebook team to start with python3?

Answer (score 0):

It works

```
conf = open('/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2/kernel.json')
conf.readline()
conf.readline()
str = conf.readline()

if str[18] != "3":
  print("old python")
  !sed -i '2!s/python/python3/' /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2/kernel.json
else:
  print("python 3 activated")
```